# three books and notebooks

Tags: meaning, numbers

a. Three books and notebooks were on the floor.

Does that mean that there were either one book and two notebooks or two notebooks and one book on the floor?

Is the sentences grammatically correct?

Could it have any other meaning?

Answer (score 3):

The sentence is grammatically correct, but ambiguous. It could mean that three books and three notebooks are on the floor, or that three items altogether are on the floor, made up of an unspecified number of books and an unspecified number of notebooks.